# Profile active for path

Tags: spring, spring-boot

### Issue

- In order to separate the development environment, we divided the environment into three types: development, stage, and prod.
- Also, I separated the yaml files under the package name env and config to separate them according to the purpose.
- Below is an example of that

```markdown
src
 |
 main
    |__  java
    |__  resources
               |___ application.yml
               |___ env
               |        |___ application-develop.yml
               |        |___ application-prod.yml
               |        |___ application-stage.yml
               |___ config
                          |___ application-youtube.yml
                          |___ application-jwt.yml
                          |___ application-oauth.yml
```

- Also, below is the structure of the develop, prod, and stage yaml files.

```markdown
spring:
    mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
  profiles:
    include:
      - youtube
      - oauth-prod
      - jwt
      - redis
      active: youtube, oauth-prod, jwt, redis

      config:
        name: application-prod,application-youtube,application-oauth-prod,application-jwt,application-redis
        location: classpath:/env/application-prod.yml,classpath:/config/application-youtube.yml,classpath:/config/application-oauth-prod.yml,classpath:/config/application-jwt.yml,classpath:/config/application-redis.yml


  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/whatsong
    maximum-pool-size: '4'
    username: root
    password: root1234
  ######################################################################
  # JPA Settings
  ######################################################################
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    format_sql: true
    use_sql_comments: true
```

```markdown
# application.yml
spring:
 profiles:
   active : /env/develop
```

### Question

- Why doesn't the YAML file work when it has the same structure as above?

  - To ask you a more detailed question, is 'ContextLoader' unable to find the yaml file even though it explicitly declared the path?
- What should I do if I want to save it separately?
- Is it a good structure to explicitly separate yaml files and multiple settings yaml files according to the environment?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good structure to separate the files by environment. I do this all the time and it works really well

> What should I do if I want to save it separately?

Exactly like you did, but I personally would keep the application-X.yml files on the same level as the application.yml file.

1. I suspect the problem is that you set the active profile not correctly.

   spring:
   profiles:
   active : /env/develop

Here you say that the active profile is "/env/develop". Try changing it to this:

```
spring:
 profiles:
   active : develop
```

**PS: Also not sure if that changes but in the documentation it tells you to set the location of other config files via `spring.config.location` . Was this a mistake on your side?**